# aiogram python ошибка

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

line 126, in 
@dp.callback_query_handler(reg_callback.filter(status="0"))
NameError: name 'reg_callback' is not defined

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Anketa.age, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def confirmation(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(age=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, "Анкета успешно заполнена, после проверки вы получите ответ."
    )
    # Отправляем сообщение в чат админов с анкетой и добавляем 2 инлайн кнопки с callback данными
    await bot.send_message(
        admin_chat_id,
        f"Поступила заявка от @{message.from_user.username}\n\n"
        f'Количество часов: {data.get("hours")}\n'
        f'Возраст: {data.get("age")}',
        reply_markup=inline(
            f"{message.chat.id}",
            f"{message.from_user.username}",
            f'{data.get("hours")}',
            f"{data.get('age')}",
        ),
    )
    # Заканчиваем "опрос"
    await state.finish()


@dp.callback_query_handler(reg_callback.filter(status="0"))
# callback данные мы сразу же приобразуем в словарь для удобства работы
async def decline(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    await call.answer()
    print(call.message.message_id, "decl")
    # Редачим сообщение в чате админов
    await bot.edit_message_text(
        "Заявка отклонена", admin_chat_id, call.message.message_id
    )
    # Отправляем вердикт.
    await bot.send_message(int(callback_data.get("chat_id")), "Ваша заявка на вступление была отклонена")


@dp.callback_query_handler(reg_callback.filter(status="1"))
async def accept(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    await call.answer()
    print(call.message.message_id, "conf")
    await bot.edit_message_text(
        "Заявка одобрена", admin_chat_id, call.message.message_id
    )
    # Отправляем вердикт.
    await bot.send_message(
        int(callback_data.get("chat_id")), "Добро пожаловать в нашу дружную тиму"
    )
    # Добавляем работника в БД

    cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET status = ?', (1,))
    cursor.execute('UPDATE hours SET balance = ?', (callback_data.get("hours"),))
    cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET age = ?', (callback_data.get("age")))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: А что это за чудо такое reg_callback?

Comment: типо спрашивает у создателя бота и возращает решение

Comment: я отсюда взял скрипт и переделал под себя https://lolz.guru/threads/2427396/